# Can Wine emulate Windows 95?

Tags: compatibility, wine, fedora-15, windows-95

I have VirtualPool2 for [Windows 95](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_95), but recently the CD drive has not been working on my Windows 95 machine. VPool only supports Windows 95, so I can't run it in [Wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29), it detects Wine as a [Windows NT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT) environment.

Is there some way to configure Wine to emulate Windows 95, or is there another emulator I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `winecfg` to modify the default version of Windows emulated or to modify settings for specific executables.

Comment: it installs, but when I run it it displays "VirtualPool CD not in drive"

Comment: Sounds like you need to ask a separate question for that.

Comment: And you'll need an older version of wine. Current versions (I checked wine 1.7) report the _oldest_ Windows version they will report to applications as Windows XP.

Answer (score 9):

If you're running a 64-bit system, you'll need to [create a 32-bit Wine prefix](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#32_bit_wineprefix) to mimic older versions of Windows (older than [Windows XP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP)).

Specify the architecture, and a new path to use for the prefix:

`WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=/path/to/wineprefix winecfg`

Configure Wine for the application as needed. There will be more Windows versions listed. Then run:

`WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=/path/to/wineprefix wine virus.exe`

Or whatever it is that you need to run.

Comment: ...and I've come full circle. Searched for the same problem and found my own solution, only noticing when I tried to upvote...

Comment: The link is half broken. Is it [this one](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#How_do_I_create_a_32_bit_wineprefix_on_a_64_bit_system.3F)?

Answer (score 0):

[DOSBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOSBox) has *some* support for Windows 95... And it is open source.

Comment: I found only one citation in some document "Note: Windows 95 on DOSBox is just a toy. It’s not recommended for any serious work. Those who need Windows 95 for some productive purpose, or even for running games, are most likely better off using something like Virtualbox or Qemu." https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hvgFvAYjPG93h-Avun3sprvZX2GfkRhl4YJBT15FTx0/ 
Later on that link: "DOSBox does not support running Windows 95 (or indeed anything that isn’t a game)."
Nothing in the official documents. Could you please provide a link for your statement?

Comment: Only that I have ran it myself. I do not have the documentation on this computer (that was almost 8 years ago that I wrote the answer, and likely a couple years earlier that I did it)

Comment: I think that DOSBox might have changed during that time. When I tried to call an EXE file from that, it automatically called `win that-EXE`, and complained that the `win` command was missing. Anyway maybe you are right in that it "has SOME support".